# How to make this regex non-greedy

Tags: java, regex

```
String input = "<p>...<mfrac><mn>[format(((([[B]])*([[C]]))),\"###,##0.######\")]</mn><mn>[[D]]</mn></mfrac></math></p>";
String result = input.replaceAll("<mfrac>(<mn>\\[[^\\\\]+]</mn>)", "<mfrac><mrow>$1</mrow>");
```

Output:

```
<p>...<mfrac><mrow><mn>[format(((([[B]])*([[C]]))),"###,##0.######")]</mn><mn>[[D]]</mn></mrow></mfrac></math></p>
```

Wanted:

```
<p>...<mfrac><mrow><mn>[format(((([[B]])*([[C]]))),"###,##0.######")]</mn></mrow><mn>[[D]]</mn></mfrac></math></p>
```

How can I make the regex not greedy? I tried adding "?". Did not help.
[image]

Comment: Where did you add `?`? Note that html isn't a regular language, so it's not always an effective solution. What are examples of inputs for this regex?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/111143

Answer (score 1):

With question marks, as the docs say. Evidently you didn't put the questionmark in the right place.

```
You have: input.replaceAll("<mfrac>(<mn>\\[[^\\\\]+]</mn>)", "<mfrac><mrow>$1</mrow>");
You need: input.replaceAll("<mfrac>(<mn>\\[[^\\\\]+?]</mn>)", "<mfrac><mrow>$1</mrow>");
```

Note that HTML isn't regular so none of this is a good idea. Use JSoup or a similar tool (something that parses *html*), modify the tree it gives you, re-render the tree back out to HTML, that's the right approach.

Comment: Thank you. and how about this one? this one for replacing second "<mn>[[D]]</mn>" or first for the end ; result = result.replaceAll("(<mn>\\[[^\\\\]+]</mn>)</mfrac>", "<mrow>$1</mrow></mfrac>");